# How to tag using JGit

Tags: eclipse, git, jgit

I am new in JGit. I am working on applying a tag to a particular file or folder available the in repository. But it's applying the tag to the whole repository. Is there any way to apply a tag for a particular folder using JGit?

Comment: What exactly are 'labels'? If you refer to [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) I suggest rephrasing your question to use the term 'tag'. That will help others find the post more easily

Comment: By mistake i have added Label in place of tag, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: A tag is pointing to a commit and thus it cannot point to a single file but always will point to the state of the full directory at a certain point in time. You would need to branch and remove others and then apply a tag to get something similar to what you describe

Answer (score -2):

So, I am not sure what you are trying to do, but (e/j)git doesn't tag or label individual files, it tags commits.  One way around this is to commit that one file and tag it with the information you want.  One way to do this:

```
$ git tag example
```

This creates a lightweight tag as a reference in .git/refs/tags/example, which points to the current commit. If we want to make it as an annotated tag, we need to supply -a, and a message with -m:

```
$ git tag -a v1 -m "Version 1 release"
```

This will create an annotated tag object, containing the message and a pointer to the commit object. Now the reference in .git/refs/tags/v1 will point to the tag object, which then points to the commit.

To list the repository's tags, run:

```
$ git tag
```

If you'd rather use Eclipse for this:

1. Switch to Git Repository Perspective
2. Check out the local branch to tag into the Git Repositories View
3. In the project tree right click on Tags -> Create Tag
4. Enter tag name and tag message.

After this the tag must be pushed to the remote repository, but that is something that can be made in the regular coding perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your ans, I have noticed that It's tagging recent commit(Master) only, Is it true? I have used following api for tag. Ref tag = git.tag().setName(label).setForceUpdate(true).call();

Comment: Yes, it tags the current commit pointer. You might be able to change that with the API, but I haven't played with that side much.

Comment: This answer does not address how to tag with the JGit API at all.